# How to sets generic values in android manifest file or any other res folder using asset in android

Tags: android, android-assets

e.g : I Want to change application logo and name, as per clients change so how can I do that very specific way in android.

Comment: http://envyandroid.com/archives/301/change-the-android-app-icon

Comment: Thanx, but my question is how to set that using assets in android, Is that possible or not.....